# How do you specify orientation with MUI5 breakpoints

Tags: material-ui

I am migrating to MUI5 and previously I was targeting landscape orientation like so:

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape)
```

Now I want to use MUI5 breakpoints, with the sx prop. I don't see any docs how to achieve this.

Something like this:

```
top: { sm: "30%", "sm and (orientation:landscape)": "10px" },
```

Obviously doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries inside `sx` as a string like this:

```
<Box sx={{
      top: {
         sm: "30%",
      },
      "@media screen and (orientation: landscape)": {
         top: {
           sm: "10px",
         }
      }
    }}
/>
```